# Glassfish v4 not logging log4j2 statements

Tags: glassfish, log4j, glassfish-4

I am using glassfish v4 with struts 2.I am also using log4j 2 but for some reasons I dont see any logs being generated by glassfish. I have log level set at info at glassfish.

I have also observed that intermittently it just don't log anything.However logging happens if I restart server, I see all startup events logged but no application logs.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that in Glassfish console if this message is appearing:

`ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.`

Your log4j2.xml has to be in WEB-INF/ just like web.xml